# DAX ignore visual filter context but keep slicer (or other visual) filter context

Tags: powerbi, dax

I would like to show in a Table Visual only the values that have been highlighted in a Matrix Visual.

[image]

When we click on the `4` value in Matrix, only then I would like to show details of that selection in Table visual. If the matrix visual is not filtered, then Table visual should not show any values. (Values in Table visual are ticked with "Don't summarize" option, because I want to see all the rows that match highlight.)

[image]

I tried to solve it by DAX measure that I might put on a visual filter:

```
ShowValues = HASONEVALUE( Tab[Fruit] ) && HASONEVALUE( Tab[Color] )
```

This measure correctly returns value if we put it on a card. But it does not filter anything on Table visual because it gets filter context from Fruit and Color columns and that is why this condition is always TRUE in that visual, because it always has one value for Fruit and Color.

How to deduce in one visual (table) that another visual (matrix) has only one value highlighted?

```
Tab = 
DATATABLE (
    "Fruit", STRING,
    "Color", STRING,
    "Values", INTEGER,
    {
        { "Apple", "red"    , 1 },
        { "Apple", "yellow" , 2 },
        { "Pearl", "red"    , 3 },
        { "Pearl", "yellow" , 1 },
        { "Pearl", "yellow" , 3 }
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem may be approached with ALLSELECTED function:

```
ShowValues2 =
IF (
    CALCULATE (
        HASONEVALUE ( Tab[Fruit] ) && HASONEVALUE ( Tab[Color] ),
        ALLSELECTED ()
    ),
    1,
    BLANK()
)
```

Option 1.
We can add this measure to filter pane of the table visual and set its value to 1.

Option 2. Alternatively, we may add this measure to values of the table visual and it will automatically show the non-blank results only. This option is visibly faster than the option 1.

[image]

Edit. If the circumstances involve dimension tables, code becomes more tricky.

```
ShowValues3 = 
IF(
    CALCULATE(
        HASONEVALUE( dim_Fruits[Fruit] ) && HASONEVALUE( dim_Colors[Color] ),
        ALLSELECTED()
    )
        && HASONEVALUE( Fact[Values] ),
    1
)
```

ALLSELECTED function has to be applied to dimensions only.

Update. For performance reasons I ended up with:

```
SWITCH( TRUE(),
    NOT (COUNTROWS( Fact ) ) = 1, BLANK(),
    NOT (CALCULATE( HASONEVALUE( Dim_Fruits[Fruit] ), ALLSELECTED( Dim_Fruits[Fruit] ) ) ), BLANK(),
    NOT (CALCULATE( HASONEVALUE( Dim_Colors[Color] ), ALLSELECTED( Dim_Colors[Color] ) ) ), BLANK(),
    1
)
```